# Center a graphic with css pseudo elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to center a graphic in a css pseudo class but it doesn't work. I tried the following:

```
#login .login:before {
    content: url('../images/lglp.png');
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

Has anyone an idea?

You can see it [here](http://gaujugend.schuetzengau-donau-ries.de/OnlinemelderApp) in live!

Comment: Why don't you consider adding a new div or img instead of that .login:before style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correct what you want, you have to give the `width` and change the `display` from `inline-block` to `block`

```
#login .login:before {
    content: url('../images/lglp.png');
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:32px;
}
```

`width` has to be the image width